# Wordpress Parsing Array in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I parse this in PHP:

```
a:8:{s:3:"key";s:19:"field_501743d4baa78";s:5:"label";s:8:"Category";s:4:"name";s:8:"category";s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:12:"instructions";s:0:"";s:8:"required";s:1:"1";s:7:"choices";a:17:{s:4:"Arts";s:4:"Arts";s:8:"Business";s:8:"Business";s:14:"Communications";s:14:"Communications";s:16:"Criminal Justice";s:16:"Criminal Justice";s:13:"Culinary Arts";s:13:"Culinary Arts";s:9:"Education";s:9:"Education";s:11:"Engineering";s:11:"Engineering";s:11:"Health Care";s:11:"Health Care";s:22:"Information Technology";s:22:"Information Technology";s:13:"International";s:13:"International";s:5:"Legal";s:5:"Legal";s:17:"Political Science";s:17:"Political Science";s:10:"Psychology";s:10:"Psychology";s:8:"Religion";s:8:"Religion";s:7:"Science";s:7:"Science";s:9:"Technical";s:9:"Technical";s:10:"Veterinary";s:10:"Veterinary";}s:8:"order_no";s:1:"3";}
```

to get a list of all the "categorys" such as Arts, Business, Communications etc etc

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**

After running unserialize this is what i get:

```
array(8) { ["key"]=> string(19) "field_501743d4baa78" ["label"]=> string(8) "Category" ["name"]=> string(8) "category" ["type"]=> string(8) "checkbox" ["instructions"]=> string(0) "" ["required"]=> string(1) "1" ["choices"]=> array(17) { ["Arts"]=> string(4) "Arts" ["Business"]=> string(8) "Business" ["Communications"]=> string(14) "Communications" ["Criminal Justice"]=> string(16) "Criminal Justice" ["Culinary Arts"]=> string(13) "Culinary Arts" ["Education"]=> string(9) "Education" ["Engineering"]=> string(11) "Engineering" ["Health Care"]=> string(11) "Health Care" ["Information Technology"]=> string(22) "Information Technology" ["International"]=> string(13) "International" ["Legal"]=> string(5) "Legal" ["Political Science"]=> string(17) "Political Science" ["Psychology"]=> string(10) "Psychology" ["Religion"]=> string(8) "Religion" ["Science"]=> string(7) "Science" ["Technical"]=> string(9) "Technical" ["Veterinary"]=> string(10) "Veterinary" } ["order_no"]=> string(1) "3" }
```

however i'm not sure how to loop through and just get the category names - sorry - i'm new to PHP - probably just doing something stupid - thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just a serialized array. Just unserialize it and getting the values is easy:

```
$array = unserialize(a:8:{s:3:"key";s:19:"field_501743d4baa78";s:5:"label";s:8:"Category";s:4:"name";s:8:"category";s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:12:"instructions";s:0:"";s:8:"required";s:1:"1";s:7:"choices";a:17:{s:4:"Arts";s:4:"Arts";s:8:"Business";s:8:"Business";s:14:"Communications";s:14:"Communications";s:16:"Criminal Justice";s:16:"Criminal Justice";s:13:"Culinary Arts";s:13:"Culinary Arts";s:9:"Education";s:9:"Education";s:11:"Engineering";s:11:"Engineering";s:11:"Health Care";s:11:"Health Care";s:22:"Information Technology";s:22:"Information Technology";s:13:"International";s:13:"International";s:5:"Legal";s:5:"Legal";s:17:"Political Science";s:17:"Political Science";s:10:"Psychology";s:10:"Psychology";s:8:"Religion";s:8:"Religion";s:7:"Science";s:7:"Science";s:9:"Technical";s:9:"Technical";s:10:"Veterinary";s:10:"Veterinary";}s:8:"order_no";s:1:"3";});
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I updated my question - it looks like unserialize gets me closer but i'm still kinda confused on how to get it completely done - thanks so much

Comment: Now that it's unserialized, it's just an array - use `foreach` to loop over it and get out whatever information you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sample_arr = unserialize($array); //unserialize here
$sample_arr = $sample_arr['choices']; //get the array
```

then you have the category list saved to $sample_arr.

```
foreach($sample_arr as $temp) {
  //do stuff with each element here
}
```

Examples include outputting this as a html list

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach($sample_arr as $temp) {
  echo '<li>' . $temp . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```